# Publish apps for different versions?

Tags: ios, app-store

Do I have to make different apps for different iOS versions?
Isn't there any backward compatibility?

Comment: Can you please more elaborate your problem?

Comment: You don't generally need to release different versions. You specify the minimum version that your app supports when you build it. If you use APIs or features that were introduced with a specific version then you either need to specify that as the minimum version or write adaptive code - for example, the method for requesting permission to issue notifications changed between iOS7 and iOS8 - you can either target iOS8 as the minimum version or specify iOS7 and write code that checks the version and calls the appropriate methods

Comment: What do you mean with different versions?? do you mean that you have to support differente iOS versions or that you have to support differente languages??

Comment: Have you done any research whatsoever? This could easily be answered by reading the Apple Documentation. Please do research before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to make different apps for different iOS versions. You need to set a Deployment Target that will be your lower desired supported iOS version. For example, if you set iOS 7.0, it will support iOS 7, 8 and 9 once it comes (that does not mean it won't crash for any of them if you use incompatible APIs!).

You can set it selecting your Target (blue icon with your app name in your project navigator in Xcode), in General tab, the Deployment Target:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. iOS has backward compatibility. Just need 1 app for different iOS versions. You can set minimum deployment target for the app.